# New Instances of Excel on 32 and 64 Bit Machines

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am trying to ensure that when the workbook I am using crashes, my other workbooks won't crash with them.  I have found that opening workbooks in separate instances of Excel prevent them from crashing each other.

I can install either Excel 2013 32 bit or Excel 2010 64 bit (I'm running a 64 bit machine).  Which version can handle more instances?  I know the 64 bit version of 2010 has larger memory limits, but I'm not sure how this translates (if at all) to instances.

Comment: "Which version can handle more instances?" - They can handle the same number of instances.  Only Excel 2016 has seen significant improvements with regards to previous limitations due to Excel being a 32-bit program.  In most cases the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit Excel was very minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using truly separate instances, then there is no "better" version in terms of the amount of instances.
They are all separate and thus independent from one another.

The 64-bit version will be able to handle bigger and more complex workbooks, due to the ability to handle more memory. ([Source 1](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Choose-between-the-64-bit-or-32-bit-version-of-Office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1), [Source 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tom/2008/04/10/chat-question-memory-limits-for-32-bit-and-64-bit-processes/))

Opening a workbook in a new instance can be done by hold the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key while the workbook is being opened. ([Source](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2013/06/03/opening-workbooks-by-running-separate-instances-of-excel/))

Appendix: The instance limit is dependent on the OS architecture (32-bit vs. 64-bit), again because of the memory limit. There is no clear limit of processes or threads on 64-bit OSes (4294967292 aka. the biggest number less than or equal to `DWORD_MAX` that is divisible by 4 is the highest process ID) ([Source 1](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/07/05/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/), [Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17868538/4867727))

Comment: Can you please source your answer?

Comment: My question is about instances, not memory management.  Please source the first portion of your answer

Comment: Great, can you source it?

Comment: Added it. TL;DR: You are limited by memory, not by some arbitrary limit. If you need to ask about the limits of the OS, you are doing something wrong (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070301-00/?p=27803)